# How to replace a list within a list?

Tags: list

What would be the an efficient/concise way to replace a sub-list with another list?

Example function call:

```el
(replace-list-list-with-list '("A" "B" "C" "D") '("B" "C") '("NEW" "TEXT"))
```

Would result in:

```el
'("A" "NEW" "TEXT" "D")
```

Comment: Why `'("B")` and not `"B"`?  Is your requirement actually more complex than stated?

Comment: Also, are you looking to create a *new* list, or to *modify* the original list?  And likewise, should the replacement list be used directly, or copied?  You're using a lot of quoted constants in your example code, which makes things trickier if you want to use or modify them directly.  Consider changing them all to `(list "A" "B" "C")` etc to ensure the code wouldn't be modified in the process.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @phils it was just to keep the example short, edited the example.

Comment: Which means that now you've changed your stated requirement of "replace a list item" to "replace a sub-list -- which makes it a different question (after answers have already been provided).

Comment: The answer from @xuchunyang works with both (before, after edit).

Comment: Substantially changing the minimal working example in the question *after* multiple people have posted answers renders one or more of those answers obsolete -- those forum participants who posted answers have essentially wasted their time.  I deleted my answer based thereon.

Comment: @ideasman42 The irritating thing is that I *specifically asked you*, little more than an hour after you posted the question, whether you were actually asking a more complicated question which would require that argument to be a list (despite *all* of the wording of the question being to the contrary).  You ignored that query, despite having made unrelated edits to the question in the interim, which indicates that you would definitely have seen it.

Comment: Then, two days later, after multiple people have expended their personal time and effort to help you, you choose to reveal that yes -- in fact you'd asked the wrong question; and instead of respecting those efforts and posting your other question separately, you decide to change this question, in the process invalidating two thirds of the answers that people had written.  The *only* reason that one of the answers matches both questions was that one person decided to answer a more general question than you had actually asked.

Comment: Leaving the question as it was and posting your other question as a new/separate question would have meant that *each* question then existed on the site with answers that actually matched the question, and without messing anyone around.

Comment: @phils, my bad for not being clear enough in the first place, however, I did have a list for the argument which you assumed didn't need to be a list and changed. The reason I made it a list was so it was clear there could be any number of items in it. Also, the question it's self _"replace a list within a list"_ hints that it's not _"replace a single value with a list in a list"_. I was trying to give a short example, but I can see how it could have been interpreted as you did.

Comment: I'll leave it at this: I am *genuinely perplexed* that you haven't yet reverted this and added the second question separately.  I suggest that you do so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nondestructive soultion which is easy to code/understand, `my-sublist-find` searches for a sublist and `my-sublist-replace` replace a sublist.

```el
(defun my-sublist-find (list sublist)
  "Find the first occurrence of SUBLIST in LIST.
Return the indexes of the matching item or nil if not found."
  (when (and list sublist (>= (length list) (length sublist)))
    (cl-loop for start from 0 to (- (length list) (length sublist))
             for end = (+ start (length sublist))
             when (equal (cl-subseq list start end) sublist)
             return (list start end))))

(defun my-sublist-replace (list1 start end list2)
  "Replace the elements of LIST1 from START to END with the elements of LIST2."
  (nconc (seq-subseq list1 0 start)
         (copy-sequence list2)
         (seq-subseq list1 end)))

(let ((list (list "A" "B" "C" "D"))
      (old (list "B" "C"))
      (new (list "NEW" "TEXT")))
  (pcase (my-sublist-find list old)
    (`(,start ,end)
     (my-sublist-replace list start end new))))
;; => ("A" "NEW" "TEXT" "D")
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Edit: This answer is for the original question of replacing a list **item**, rather than for the modified question of replacing a sub-list.  Extending this approach to recognise sub-lists is left as an exercise for the reader.)*

Here's a destructive approach (but don't use it unless you *know* that you want a destructive approach -- definitely don't do so with *quoted* lists, like there are in the example in the question).

```el
(defun replace-list-item-with-list (list item replacement)
  "Substitute a REPLACEMENT list for ITEM in LIST, by altering the lists."
  (catch 'substitution
    (let ((current list)
          parent)
      (while current
        (if (not (equal (car current) item))
            (setq parent current
                  current (cdr current))
          (if parent
              (setcdr parent (nconc replacement (cdr current)))
            (setq list (nconc replacement (cdr current))))
          (throw 'substitution t)))))
  list)
```

```
(replace-list-item-with-list (list "A" "B" "C") "A" (list "NEW" "TEXT"))
=> ("NEW" "TEXT" "B" "C")

(replace-list-item-with-list (list "A" "B" "C") "B" (list "NEW" "TEXT"))
=> ("A" "NEW" "TEXT" "C")

(replace-list-item-with-list (list "A" "B" "C") "C" (list "NEW" "TEXT"))
=> ("A" "B" "NEW" "TEXT")

(replace-list-item-with-list (list "A" "B" "C") "D" (list "NEW" "TEXT"))
=> ("A" "B" "C")
```

Assuming LIST is actually a variable, you would (as usual) need to *assign* the return value back to the list variable to handle the case where the *first* item was replaced.

```el
(setq list (replace-list-item-with-list list item replacement))
```

---

FWIW I note that the `dash` package has:

```el
(-splice-list (lambda (x) (equal x "B"))
              (list "NEW" "TEXT")
              (list "A" "B" "C"))
```

Comment: n.b. I didn't make the second argument a list, as no purpose was indicated for that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic function that replaces a list within a list N times, taking an optional comparitor argument.

```el
(defun my-list-replace-list-in-list (lst src dst &rest keyword-args)
  "Replace the list SRC with DST in LST, returning a new list with the replacement(s) made.

Optional keyword arguments are:

:test TEST -- Defines how list items are compared, defaulting to `eq'.

:count COUNT -- The number of replacements to make, defaulting to nil (replace all)."
  (let ((result (list)) ;; Build new list.
        (current-count 0)
        (lst-iter lst)

        ;; Keyword arguments.
        (comparitor #'eq)
        (count nil))

    ;; Extract keyword args.
    (let ((kw-iter keyword-args))
      (while kw-iter
        (let ((kw-key (pop kw-iter))
              (kw-val (pop kw-iter)))
          (cond
           ((eq kw-key :test)  (setq comparitor kw-val))
           ((eq kw-key :count) (setq count kw-val))
           (t (error "Unknown keyword argument %S" kw-key))))))

    (while lst-iter
      (unless
          (let ((found t) ;; Assume found until the match differs.
                (src-iter src)
                (lst-iter-test lst-iter))
            (while src-iter
              (if (and lst-iter-test (funcall comparitor (car lst-iter-test) (car src-iter)))
                  (progn
                    (setq src-iter (cdr src-iter))
                    (setq lst-iter-test (cdr lst-iter-test)))
                ;; Exit.
                (setq src-iter nil)
                (setq found nil)))
            (when found
              (let ((dst-iter dst))
                (while dst-iter
                  (push (car dst-iter) result)
                  (setq dst-iter (cdr dst-iter))))
              (setq current-count (1+ current-count))
              ;; Always fail when `count' is nil.
              (if (eq current-count count)
                  ;; All replacements made, finish and exit.
                  (progn
                    (while lst-iter-test
                      (push (car lst-iter-test) result)
                      (setq lst-iter-test (cdr lst-iter-test)))
                    ;; Break the main loop.
                    (setq lst-iter nil))
                ;; Keep replacing.
                (setq lst-iter lst-iter-test))
              t))
        ;; No match, build list one by one.
        (push (car lst-iter) result)
        (setq lst-iter (cdr lst-iter))))
    (nreverse result)))
```

Example use:

```el
(let ((list (list "A" "B" "C" "D" "A" "B" "C" "D"))
      (src (list "C" "D"))
      (dst (list "NEW" "TEXT")))
  (message
    "Result %S"
    (my-list-replace-list-in-list list src dst :test #'string-equal)))
```

Outputs:

```
Result ("A" "B" "NEW" "TEXT" "A" "B" "NEW" "TEXT")
```